# svn2git: Cannot setup tracking information

Tags: git, svn2git

I am trying to migrate a SVN project to git with thel help of svn2git. When executing the command it exits with the following error:

```
Running command: git branch --track "0.0.9" "remotes/svn/0.0.9"
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'remotes/svn/0.0.9' is not a branch.
```

Started it with:

```
 svn2git http://<host>/<project>
```

I can't find any solution for it and it seems not many users has the same problem.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What command did you execute?

Comment: Edited the start post with execution command

Comment: Try running it witr `-v`, might print some useful debugging information, including output from git which made it believe there is such a remote branch.

Comment: this should fix it: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/132#issuecomment-31453436

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem using Debian Sid (the version of "git" is 1:1.8.3.2-1). Before I already failed on Debian Squeeze using the stock "git" package (1:1.7.2.5-3).
Finally I ended up using the squeeze-backport repository (1:1.7.10.4-1~bpo60+1), and now it works.

What version of Git are you using?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, git 1.8.1.3 works fine but updating to 1.8.3.3 generates the mentioned error.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reaction. Downgrading to a 1.7 works for me also. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I also needed to downgrade from git 1.8.4 to 1.7.12.4 for the tracking to work. Doing this with Homebrew was easy enough: `cd /user/local/Library/Formula && git checkout 7f1a8c0 /usr/local/Library/Formula/git.rb && brew unlink git && brew install git`.

Comment: I have the same problem with Homebrew-installed git 1.8.4.  Using Apple-installed /usr/bin/git 1.8.3.1 let me create the tracking branches.

Comment: Thank you for the great information. Had the same issue, was using v1.8.4

Comment: Git 1.8.3.1 is the last version that works with the current release 2.2.2 of svn2git. A few days ago a fix was integrated into svn2git, but there's no official release yet. [Here's the GitHub issue](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/132)] if you want to look into it (apparently the fix is pretty simple, just a command line option of `git branch` that needed to be removed).

Comment: @Jason McCreary I'm glad that it works now for you, happy migrating to Git =)

Comment: @pderaaij normally my answer should be accepted because using an older Git release is not the solution ;-)

Answer (score 7):

this should fix it:

Changing this line https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/blob/master/lib/svn2git/migration.rb#L319
from `run_command("git branch --track \"#{branch}\" \"remotes/svn/#{branch}\"")`
to `run_command("git branch \"#{branch}\" \"remotes/svn/#{branch}\"")`
should fix it.

At least it works now for me without any issues.

you can find the `migration.rb` file on Windows under `C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\svn2git-2.2.2\lib\svn2git` or something like this

https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/132#issuecomment-31453436

Comment: This is still necessary on Ubuntu 14.04, so presumably a new release hasn't been push to wherever gem install downloads packages from.

Comment: I don't know why there is no new release but they should push one to solve the problem.

But I, personally, think the solution which I have mentioned is the best solution and should work on all systems and be compatible with them. But I didn't test this.

Comment: I updated my svn2git and it fixed the issue. `gem update svn2git`

Comment: right Nate, this is now officially fixed and released

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a quick and dirty solution to this without changing code!

Every time you get the error, just manually change branch and continue your `svn2git` command.

so to go through the workflow:

#### Running the command

```
svn2git ....
```

#### Got the error

```
Running command: git branch --track "0.0.9" "remotes/svn/0.0.9"
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'remotes/svn/0.0.9' is not a branch.
```

#### Manually change branch (Copy the `Running command:` line and removing `--track`)

```
branch "0.0.9" "remotes/svn/0.0.9"
```

#### Continuing with `svn2git`

```
svn2git ...
```

*note `...` after the `svn2git` above is whatever your svn2git command is*

Comment: this can take a while when you have many branches and have to do this manually instead of changing the code (so it works always)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small number of branches and don't want to downgrade git, here's a way to workaround the issue. Run "git branch -r" to get a list of the branches. Then run the following for each branch (named svn/next_branch for example):

```
$ git branch "next_branch" "remotes/svn/next_branch"
```

The only difference is the "--track" option is removed.

That was the fix applied for this [Github Issue](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/132)