# git-svn: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point is not a branch

Tags: git, git-svn

In git 1.7.9.5 I could run the following lines without error:

```
export SVNPASS=readonly
git clone git@github.com:dtenenbaum/RGalaxy.test.git
cd RGalaxy.test/
git config --add svn-remote.hedgehog.url https://hedgehog.fhcrc.org/bioconductor/trunk/madman/Rpacks/RGalaxy
git config --add svn-remote.hedgehog.fetch :refs/remotes/hedgehog
# the following is a shortcut to avoid fetching every commit since antiquity, since I happen to know the commit number
# where this folder was added to svn:
echo $SVNPASS | git svn fetch --username readonly hedgehog -r 65762:HEAD
git checkout -b local-hedgehog -t hedgehog
```

In git 1.8.3.4 and 1.8.4.1 that last line results in:

```
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'hedgehog' is not a branch.
```

The comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852249/svn2git-cannot-setup-tracking-information) suggest downgrading, but I'd like to know why this is happening: is it a bug? And if so, has it been reported? Or is there a better way to do this and if so, what is it?

Incidentally, "git branch -a" returns:

```
* master
  remotes/hedgehog
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 43):

This is not considered as a bug by git-svn developpers. As a matter of fact, this is a result of a bug fix in v1.8.3.2. Setting up your local `local-hedgehog` to track git-svn's `hedgehog` will no longer work.

From now on, simply doing

```
git checkout -b hedgehog remotes/hedgehog
```

is enough to be able to do all your usual git-svn operations (`git svn rebase`, `git svn dcommit`, etc.).

Here is the explanation by Johan Herland:

> Prior to v1.8.3.2 this still sort-of works (as you observe below),
>   because the code fails to realize the remote is invalid, and falls back
>   to setting branch.feat-bar.remote = "." (i.e. the current repo). This
>   might seem like an ok practice until you realize that a "git push" back
>   to that invalid upstream would happily overwrite
>   refs/remotes/(mirror/)feat-bar, and thus break git-svn's internal state.
>
> This bug was fixed in v1.8.3.2, more specifically 41c21f22 (branch.c:
>   Validate tracking branches with refspecs instead of refs/remotes/*),
>   and you can read more about the rationale in that commit message.
>
> The end result for you is that setting up your local feat-bar to track
>   git-svn's feat-bar will no longer be accepted once you upgrade to >=
>   v1.8.3.2. The correct way to set up a local feat-bar branch to work on
>   top of git-svn's feat-bar is instead to forgo the upstream relationship
>   and simply do "git checkout -b feat-bar refs/remotes/(mirror/)feat-bar".

If you want more details, I suggest reading his [whole post](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-svn-Use-prefix-by-default-td7594288.html#a7597159).

Comment: That sounds a bit mad on git-svn folks' side, but thanks for sharing, in easily googlable answer, hope people will get used to it.

Comment: No, wait, it's still fsckingly mad on their side. When I push somewhere (like wanting to mirror from svn to git), it won't push remotes/trunk by itself. So, I need to push that explicitly, that looks weird, will confuse people, etc., etc. It's fsckingly mad.

Comment: `git checkout -b remotes/hedgehog` does not work, and seems wrong, to me.  In that case I get a local branch called remotes/hedgehog, based off the current HEAD. The correct command is, as far as I can tell, `git checkout -b hedgehog remotes/hedgehog`. This is also the command used in Johan's explanation.

Comment: i had to use something like `git checkout -b hedgehog remotes/origin/hedgehog` (note the `origin` part) for `git version 2.24.1.windows.2`

Answer (score 6):

In SourceTree, simply remove the checkbox ticked with "local branch should track remote branch".

Answer (score 1):

there are many proposed fixes for this issue:

https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/132
https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/pull/145

in my opinion this is a bug in svn2git

Answer (score 0):

I am using this: git branch --set-upstream remotes/git-svn