# Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'origin/master' is not a branch

Tags: git

Can someone explain why this isn't working?

```
➜  workspace git:(REL-BRANCH-1.0.1d) ✗ git branch -a
  REL-BRANCH-1.0.1c
* REL-BRANCH-1.0.1d
  remotes/origin/REL-BRANCH-1.0.1c
  remotes/origin/master
➜  workspace git:(REL-BRANCH-1.0.1d) ✗ git checkout -t origin/master 
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'origin/master' is not a branch.
➜  workspace git:(REL-BRANCH-1.0.1d) ✗ git checkout -t remotes/origin/master
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'remotes/origin/master' is not a branch.
```

Comment: Try `git remote update`, and check again.

Comment: That's ... odd, to say the least.  What *is* origin/master?  What does `git branch -a -v -v` show, and what does `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin/master` produce?  It sure looks like an ordinary remote-branch...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got frustrated and completely blew away the repo and started over and the issue is resolved. If I can close this question out, I will.

Answer (score 69):

Probably your origin remote is set up to fetch only certain branches. A simple

```
git remote set-branches --add origin master
```

will fix it.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible that your repo contains config that asks fetch command to retrieve only some specific branch(es) instead of just all of them. You can check the configuration you have using

```
git config --local --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

It can return lines like `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` or `+refs/heads/AnyOtherBranch:refs/remotes/origin/AnyOtherBranch`.
The first config string means that it fetches all the branches. The second and third are examples of fetch config only for specific branches.
If you don't have config line with asterisk then you can use either

```
# Reset "remote.origin.fetch" to deal with all branches
git remote set-branches origin '*'
```

or

```
# Append new config line for specific branch
git remote set-branches --add origin AnyOtherBranch
```

Comment: `git remote set-branches origin '*'` solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can also do like this to get all branches in a folder `git remote set-branches --add origin users/myUserNameFolder/*`

Answer (score 7):

For anybody getting here via google while having the same problem (by 'the same' I mean the same error message not the same cause) with 'git svn' rather than just 'git':

Removing the -t option might help as explained in: [git-svn: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point is not a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712735/git-svn-cannot-setup-tracking-information-starting-point-is-not-a-branch/23408177)

Comment: Thanks, this is what worked finally while adding a new worktree.